# Do views filter plugins not apply to base field definitions?

Tags: views, 8, entities

I created a custom entity type that has a base field definition like this:

```
$fields['start_date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
  ->setLabel(t('Start Date'))
  ->setDescription(t('The date and time to start.'))
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'type' => 'datetime_default',
    'weight' => 3,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'datetime_default',
    'weight' => 3,
  ])
  ->setRequired(TRUE);
```

When I create a view that displays entities of this type, and try to create a filter on this base field, I get the generic filter provided by views, instead of the one defined in `Drupal\datetime\Plugin\views\filter\Date`.

Why is that?

Comment: I'm guessing https://www.drupal.org/node/2489476#comment-11891454 is you, then you figured it out by now ;) As a workaround, you can specify the filter yourself for now

Comment: hah - yes. I'm working on a hook_views_data implementation now, then will post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is a [known major issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2489476). Here's the main "parent" issue where most of the work is going down: https://www.drupal.org/node/2337515

I think, by default, there is some basic views integration for all entities, but it's not that robust.

As a workaround, I was able to implement hook_views_data_alter to tell views to use the 'datetime' filter plugin instead of the default 'string' plugin it had.

```
function MY_MODULE_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data['my_entity_type']['start_date']['filter']['id'] = 'datetime';
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what changes you made in the filter?
It seems that the MY_MODULE_run_views_data_alter does not exist, is an error and I have to use MY_MODULE_views_data_alter ?

Comment: Sorry, I that was a type in the hook name. Updated answer to fix that and removed the last bit about creating a custom filter. I think that was incorrect as well, it shouldn't have been required.

Comment: I tested and doesn't work for me, when I try to add a filter with this field, the popup window doesn't show me the options and reappear the add filter page. When I reload the edit view page, shows me this error "Notice: Undefined index: field_name in Drupal\datetime\Plugin\views\filter\Date->getFieldStorageDefinition() (line 56 of /var/www/.../core/modules/views/src/FieldAPIHandlerTrait.php)"

Answer (score 0):

An entity type can be revisionable and translatable and in these cases, the table name will not be `entity_type`. Check the `@ContentEntityType` annotation on the entity class for `data_table` and `revision_data_table` keys.

Also, the `ListField` Views filter class needs `field_name` set.

Here's a working example for a base field set on `media`:

```
function sd8_media_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data['media_field_data']['embed_status']['filter']['id'] = 'list_field';
  $data['media_field_data']['embed_status']['filter']['field_name'] = 'embed_status';
}
```

My field is not revisionable and so I didn't need to set the same on `$data['media_field_revision']` but if your field is, then you need that too. xdebug is very much your friend, put a breakpoint inside the `hook_views_data_alter` function and look at `$data`.